# Why am I getting such an error? error TS2564:

Tags: angular, typescript

import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

create-post.component.ts

```
createPostForm: FormGroup;
```

create-post.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="createPostForm" (ngSubmit)="createPost()">
```

I get the error in the createPostForm: FormGroup block I created in create-post.component.ts.

error TS2564: Property 'createPostForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in t
he constructor.

Comment: Have you set the `createPostForm` to an actual value somewhere? Just declaring it as a type isn't enough most of the time.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, isn't it? You have declared but not initialized your property `createPostForm`. Neither at declaration nor in the constructor. Assign a value to `createPostForm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should init createpost form like this:

```
createPostForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
first: new FormControl('first name'),
last: new FormControl('last name')
});
```

or

```
createPostForm: FormGroup;

constructor() {
    createPostForm=new FormGroup({
        first: new FormControl('first name'),
        last: new FormControl('last name')
   });
}
```

more info:

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset-usage-notes